# Replace values in a URI query string

Tags: php

I have part of a query string that I want to make a replacement in. I want to use `preg_replace` but am kind of hung up on the regex.

Can someone please help? What I need replaced are the GET vars.

Here is the string:

```
bikeType=G&nikeNumber=4351
```

Comment: They will be dynamically replaced.

Comment: Please can you clarify your question?  You want the regex to match what exactly?

Comment: Can't you just access the get array to read the variables from there?

Answer (score 8):

PHP has a convenient function to parse query strings: [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). You might want to take a look at that or provide more details as your question isn't exactly clear.

Comment: And to reformat the array from `parse_str`, after modification, into a string you can use `http_build_query`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `parse_str` as was mentioned already.
In addition, if you want to put them back into a query string you can use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Example:

```
parse_str('bikeType=G&nikeNumber=4351', $params);
$params['bikeType'] = 'F';
$params['nikeNumber'] = '1234';
echo http_build_query($params, '', '&amp;');
```

Output

```
bikeType=F&amp;nikeNumber=1234
```

---

Please note that you should not use `parse_str` without the second argument (or at least not with some consideration). When you leave it out, PHP will create variables from the query params in the current scope. That can lead to security issues. Malicious users could use it to overwrite other variables, e.g.

```
// somewhere in your code you assigned the current user's role
$role = $_SESSION['currentUser']['role'];
// later in the same scope you do
parse_str('bikeType=G&nikeNumber=4351&role=admin');
// somewhere later you check if the user is an admin
if($role === "admin") { /* trouble */ }
```

---

Another note: using the third param for `http_build_query` is recommended, because the proper encoding for an ampersand is `&amp;`. Some validators will complain if you put just the `&` in there.