# How to use preg_replace to do this..?

Tags: php, preg-replace

How can I use preg_replace to do this:

I want to replace:

```
<a href="index.php?option=example1&view=something">
```

with this

```
<a href="index.php?option=example2&view=somethingelse&task=task1">
```

Thanx

Comment: You might want to look into HTML parsers for complex html replacing cases, eg. php's dom lib (http://www.php.net/dom)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Comment: *(related)* [Replace values in a URI query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777481/replace-values-in-a-uri-query-string/3777523#3777523)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:

```
$url = '<a href="index.php?option=example1&view=something">';

$getInside = preg_match('/<a href=\"(.*)\">/', $url, $match);
$parse = parse_url($match[1]);

$newUrl = $parse['path']."?";
$urlArray = array();

parse_str($parse['query'], $params);

foreach($params as $key => $match){ 
    if($key == 'option'){
        $urlArray['option'] = 'example2';
    }
    if($key == 'view'){
        $urlArray['view'] = 'somethingelse';
    }
}
$urlArray['task'] = 'task1';
$newUrl .= http_build_query($urlArray, '', '&');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace

```
<a href="index.php?option=example1&view=something">
```

by

```
<a href="index.php?option=example2&view=somethingelse&task=task1">
```

:

```
preg_replace('#<a href="index\.php\?option=example1&view=something">#', '<a href="index.php?option=example2&view=somethingelse&task=task1">', $string);
```