# Changing language variable in URL

Tags: php, url, locale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace values in a URI query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777481/replace-values-in-a-uri-query-string)

I am using a language switcher in the navigation bar to switch between EN and DE, my url structure is like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/gallery.php?lang=de
http://www.mydomain.com/gallery-item.php?id=100&lang=de
```

The switch works well on all urls which don't have an id, but it doesn't work with the ids.

```
<?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
<a href='.$url.'?lang=en">
<a href='.$url.'?lang=de">
?>
```

What is a good solution to check for $lang=xx or ?lang=xx and then add ?lang=xx or $lang=xx respectively?

Comment: Are you using any htaccess code to rewrite the urls ?

Comment: Try to add the `?` only, if `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not set (this variable contains the url parameters) and add an `&` if it is set. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = $_GET;

$params['lang'] = 'en';
printf('<a href="%s?%s">En</a>', $url, http_build_query($params));

$params['lang'] = 'de';
printf('<a href="%s?%s">De</a>', $url, http_build_query($params));
```

Or even very compact:

```
printf('<a href="%s?%s">De</a>',
       $url, http_build_query(array('lang' => 'de') + $_GET));
```

http://php.net/http_build_query